# MKMapView with UserLocation crashes when dismissing view controller

Tags: ios5

I have a ViewController with a MapView that has UserLocation set and also MKUserTrackingModeFollow set.  I have my view controller as the delegate to the mapview.

When I dismiss the Viewcontroller something in the mapview still sends ClientUpdate to my viewcontroller but it crashes as it has now been deallocated.

I tried calling [self.mapView setDelegate:nil] in dealloc but still the same result.

The error is BadAcces when onClientEvent is called on my controller. I am using io5 and ARC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate to nil? Other posts mention that it is common to do it in dealloc.

Comment: I tried that as well, same thing

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by putting  [self.mapView setDelegate:nil] in viewWillDisappear.